Decoding the Use of the と Form in Place of the て Form
I have been playing The Witcher 3 in japanese and encountered this sentence: メエメエ黒ヒツジ、毛糸を少し分けとくれ！ I am curious as to why the form とくれ was used instead of てくれ. I am aware of the famous quote from Son Goku: 元気を分けてくれ. Therefore, I would like to understand the origin of the use of と in this context. What nuance or difference does it present? How can it be applied? Is there any particular reason for choosing と over the usual て-form?
Thank you in advance for your insights.

This is simply a contraction of “分けておくれ” the “お〜” is the same polite “お〜” that　can come in front of many other verbs and makes it more polite.
As far as I understand it, it mostly sounds old-fashioned and isn't used much in modern Japanese any more. I rarely see it in the wild and if I do, it's almost always part of stylized language of some fictional character supposed to speak in an old-fashioned way.
